# my chat system looks a little wierd, cant get dynamic height for cell

Tags: ios, height, messagebox, uitableview

Ive got a chat system in my app, and im attempting to make dynamic cells to have dynamic height according to how much text is in the cell, pretty common thing people try to do, however i cant get to get mine working properly.

Also the messages align to the right, the sender is supposed to be on the left and the reciever should be on the right... heres what i have done with the storyboard.

created a TableView with `2 dynamic prototypes`, inside a `UIViewController`here is the viewController for that... each cell has a label, one left one right, the whole right and left thing work... heres my issue. Its only pulling to the right for all, so basically my `if` isnt happening and my `else` is overruling. Heres a SS.

So i have two issues... Text wont have multiple lines... along with wont do dynamic height, also... if someone can point me i the right dirrection for getting sender and reciever to show on different sides.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *myWords = [[getMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@":oyr4:"];
    if (myWords[1] == [MyClass str]){
        static NSString *sender = @"sender";
        UITableViewCell* cellSender = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sender];
        messageContentTo = (UILabel *)[cellSender viewWithTag:83];
        self->messageContentTo.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.8];
        self->messageContentTo.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [self->messageContentTo sizeToFit];
        messageContentTo.text = myWords[4];
        return cellSender;
    } else {

        static NSString *reciever = @"reciever";

        UITableViewCell* cellReciever = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reciever];
        messageContentFrom = (UILabel *)[cellReciever viewWithTag:84];
        messageContentFrom.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.8];
        messageContentFrom.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        messageContentFrom.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
        messageContentFrom.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageContentFrom.text = myWords[4];

        return cellReciever;
    }

}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate methods
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = [[getMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                   sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(1000, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    return size.height + 15;
}
```

Comment: Is myWords[1] a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-right problem might be due to this:

```
if (myWords[1] == [MyClass str])
```

If myWords[1] is a string, you need to use isEqualToString: not "==" to compare it.

```
if ([myWords[1] isEqualToString:[MyClass str]])
```

As far as the label height not adjusting properly, it's hard to tell what's going on without knowing how your labels are set up. I usually do it by making constraints between the label and the top and bottom of the cell in IB. That way, when you change the height of the cell, the label will follow (and of course, set numberOfLines to 0). Also, in your sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: method, the width you pass into CGSizeMake() should be the width of the label, not 1000.

Comment: Here you are again Eric to rescue my day.. i think you have helped me way too many times tbh lol... I'll give that a shot

Comment: by changing the 1000 to a smaller amount (320) all it did was make the space (vertical) further apart from each message, Also `numberOfLines is set to 0, (and has been) still nothing, also the label constraints are set the cell and still nothing on that subject either

Comment: @AaronRussell, the fact that the messages are getting further apart indicates that your sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: method is probably working correctly. The problem still seems to be the constraints. Does you label have an explicit height set? If so, remove it. Also, you shouldn't need sizeToFit in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Had a busy day today with the kiddo's... Okay so i got the mutiple lines working, no glitching like there was before... i took away the height from the cells, and the labels and that seemed to work, however my cells themselves are overlapping and no longer a dynamic height like there was. I havnt changed any coding, just the storyboard constraints like you said

Comment: @AaronRussell, so you're saying that the cells are all the same height now? If they're overlapping, maybe you need to increase the constant here in this line: return size.height + 15;

Comment: changing the `constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, CGFLOAT_MAX)];` to 250 (the width of my label) like you said earlier fixed my auto height in the cell, then they were too spaced apart, so i did the `size.height` at a negative value and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @AaronRussell, I wonder if part of the problem is the way you calculate the height. You're using [getMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] as the string, but you're populating the label with only part of that string: [[getMessage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@":oyr4:"][4]. Shouldn't you be using that to calculate the height?

Comment: because i use the myWord array to spit out 4 different things for me, the date, the sender email the reciever email and the message, edit: Oh and the name of the reciever

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29632/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-aaron-russell)

Comment: @AaronRussell, it doesn't matter why you're doing that -- the point is, you should be calculating the size of the label with the same string you're populating it with, which doesn't appear to be the case as your code is written now.

Comment: I see what your saying, so call myWord[4]? But if i do that i would need to make that a global variable which im not so sure i can... am i right?

Comment: i will be in that discussion room